# Im concerned about my android phone

Tags: root-access, settings, lg, unrooting

So i just recently got a new phone. Android - LG K51 - however after running a root checker it says my phone has two available android versions. Android 9.0 and Android 10.0. Ive checked and the phones is running on Android 9.0. Ive also looked into the credentials and theres a whole list of apps downloaded that have the name Root in them. As well as a system file saying RootPA. Is my phone as risk or is it still safe?[image: Used Root Checker Basic located in app store.]

[image: another screenshot of the root checker.]

Comment: This website din't let me comment so I'm answering. Did you root using kingroot or something like that, if yes then flash the stock rom and try magisk,supersu. Good luck!

Comment: remove all google accounts. do factory reset. check your bootloader is locked. check if you can install OTA via settings menu. both together indicates the device is healthy

Comment: the question is tagged **unrooting** therefore i don't think OP ask about rooting. concern is about malware

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/what-is-rootpa.2824458

Comment: Just want to clarify, I assume you bought/got the (refurbished?) phone already with root apps, but not root access? And now you're trying to make sure that the device is secure/unrooted?

Answer (score 0):

The LG K51 has many variants. [All variants](https://www.phonearena.com/phones/LG-K51_id11415#section-alternative-variants) have Android 10 except the LG K51 for Boost Mobile which has Android 9.

> Ive also looked into the credentials and theres a whole list of apps downloaded that have the name Root in them. As well as a system file saying RootPA. Is my phone as risk or is it still safe?

When trying to root via 3rd party apps, they download files (and bloatware) that must be use to root. If you really want to root your phone, better search [Xda-Developers](https://xda-developers.com/) to find if there are methods for your phone instead of using the one-click apps.

Comment: @alecxs And there is also root-access tag, plus there is no mention on the OP about how to unroot the phone.

Comment: I've asked the OP to clarify the question. Currently, I'm interpreting as alecxs', but we don't really know until the OP confirms it.

Comment: @AndrewT. No problem.